# Fórmula dentro de um Campo

Tags: sql, sql-server

Em um campo possuo o valor de uma fórmula (`(B/2)+ C`), sendo que o valor **B e C** vem de outros campos, como posso trocar os valores das letras pelos seus valores reais e calcular a fórmula?

Preciso só de um norte de como fazer isso, pois não estou conseguindo achar um padrão.

OBS: Existem **n** tipos de fórmulas, não é fixo o valor.

**EDIT**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Só faço uma busca nessa tabela simples e preciso substituis o valor de B e C pelos seus valores. Depois calcular a fórmula.

```
Ex: (10/2) + 5
```

Comment: Você poderia exemplificar mais sua pergunta com exemplos de retorno da sua consulta e como é sua tabela também?

Comment: Editei, meu select é só buscar os valores, mas meu problema é como substituir esses valores e depois calcular a formula inteira.

Comment: Vide `SQL Server Eval | Dynamically evaluate arithmetic operation and expression in SQL`: https://github.com/zzzprojects/Eval-SQL.NET/wiki/SQL-Server-Eval-%7C-Dynamically-evaluate-arithmetic-operation-and-expression-in-SQL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Montei um exemplo utilizando o `exec`

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;
--crio uma tabela temporária para simular a sua tabela
CREATE TABLE #formulas_table(
formula varchar(100),
A int, 
B int,
C int)
--insiro uns dados de amostra
insert into #formulas_table
select '(B/2)+ C' formula, 10 B,5 C,0 A
union all select '(B/1)+ C' formula, 10 B,5 C,0 A
union all select '(B/3)+ C' formula, 10 B,5 C,0 A

begin --esse é o trecho que você precisa
    --declaro um cursor com os dados da tabela de amostra
    --aqui você irá substituir pelo seu select na sua tabela
    declare formulas cursor fast_forward for
    select formula
    from #formulas_table
    declare @formula varchar(100)

    --abre o cursor e atribiu o valor na variável @formula
    OPEN formulas  
    FETCH NEXT FROM formulas   
    INTO @formula

    --percorro o cursor até que não tenha mais dados
    while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
    BEGIN 
        --o exec pode ser usado para montar consultas concatenadas em uma string
        exec('select top 1 ' + @formula + ' from #formulas_table')

        --vai para o próximo item do cursor
        FETCH NEXT FROM formulas   
        INTO @formula
    END

    --fecha e libera o cursor de memória
    CLOSE formulas;  
    DEALLOCATE formulas; 
end --fim do trecho que você precisa

--dropa a tabela temporária, pois só precisei dela para montar o exemplo
drop table #formulas_table
```

Comment: Obrigado pelo script, mas poderia comentar? pois não entendi direito essa lógica.

Comment: Adicionei os comentários ao script

Comment: A entendi agora, obrigado. Mas agora com os valores concatenados como eu conseguiria executar a formula para obter o resultado dela ? tipo (10/2) + 5 => Resultado: 10

Comment: mas isso é o que o `exec('select top 1 ' + @formula + ' from #formulas_table')` faz, ele vai concatenar o resultado do @formula e ficaria algo do tipo `select top 1 (B/2)+ C from #formulas_table`

Comment: @Aprendiz A sugestão do Pablo é uma das soluções para calcular fórmulas. Se achar adequado, você pode armazenar o resultado de cada linha em uma tabela temporária e ao final listar como um único dataset.